# Is there a crosswalk table from USDA agricultural district to FIPS code?

Tags: fips

Is there a crosswalk table from USDA agricultural district to FIPS code?

USDA agricultural district https://www.nass.usda.gov/Charts_and_Maps/Crops_County/boundary_maps/asdsbig.gif

I have checked https://www.agcensus.usda.gov/Publications/2012/Online_Resources/Ag_Atlas_Maps/mapfiles/ag_co_metadata_faq_12.html#what

It seems that I have to do some complex calculation to get the crosswalk table. I do believe there is a crosswalk table from USDA agricultural district to FIPS code.

Comment: I think this is a question more suited to the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: It looks like they're using county boundaries. Are you looking for the county FIPS codes? Why can't you run an intersection (do I have the correct procedure?) using county data that has the FIPS codes?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for: https://www.nass.usda.gov/Data_and_Statistics/County_Data_Files/Frequently_Asked_Questions/county_list.txt